# Detection of USB Ethernet gadget by PyQt GUI in Windows 10

Tags: ssh, pi-zero-w, pi-zero, windows

I am looking to implement this feature where a Pi connected to Windows 10 PC is detected by a PyQt GUI on the press of a soft button or through periodical scan of connected devices. I can see Pi in Device Manager and login into it in Putty but I would like to do implement some functions that run automatically whenever Pi is detected as USB Ethernet gadget and is ready to connect to PC through SSH.

Appreciate any help in implementing this. Thanks.

Comment: what is the specific problem that you are trying to solve? ... what is your question?

Comment: @jsotola Edited the question. U may go through it again

Comment: your post is a description of what you would like to do ... there is no mention of a problem ... there is no question being asked

Answer (score 1):

Example :

> 1. Search Ethernet devices by name: `Ethernet *`
> 2. Check interface description , search : `Remote NDIS Compatible Device` or directly by the RPI MAC address.
> 3. If found, assign interface IP address
> 4. Run SSH...

In python you can run Windows system command (with python [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html)) and use Windows `WMIC` commands:

> `WMIC NIC GET /FORMAT:CSV`

and [parse the CSV](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) result to check `name`,`description` or `MAC address` to see if you RNDIS gadget is available. You can also use a filter like this :

> `WMIC NIC GET Index,Name,Description,MACAddress /FORMAT:CSV`

Some others `WMIC NIC` filters:

> Node, AdapterType, AdapterTypeId, AutoSense, Availability, Caption,
> ConfigManagerErrorCode, ConfigManagerUserConfig, CreationClassName,
> Description, DeviceID, ErrorCleared, ErrorDescription, GUID, Index,
> InstallDate, Installed, InterfaceIndex, LastErrorCode, MACAddress,
> Manufacturer, MaxNumberControlled, MaxSpeed, Name, NetConnectionID,
> NetConnectionStatus, NetEnabled, NetworkAddresses, PermanentAddress,
> PhysicalAdapter, PNPDeviceID, PowerManagementCapabilities,
> PowerManagementSupported, ProductName, ServiceName, Speed, Status,
> StatusInfo, SystemCreationClassName, SystemName, TimeOfLastReset

For example, search by MAC address (XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX = RPI MAC ADDRESS) :

`WMIC NIC WHERE (MACAddress="XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX" AND Description="Remote NDIS Compatible Device" AND NetConnectionStatus=2) GET /FORMAT:CSV`

if this command return no result (`No instances available`), then your gadget is not plugged.

**Python3.7 working code (EDIT: 03/08/2022)**:

```
from threading import Thread, Event
import time, sys, subprocess

RPI_GADGET_IF_DESC = "Remote NDIS Compatible Device"
RPI_GADGET_IF_CON  = 2

CMD = ["WMIC", "NIC", "WHERE", "(Description=\"%s\" AND NetConnectionStatus=%d)"%(RPI_GADGET_IF_DESC, RPI_GADGET_IF_CON), "GET", "/FORMAT:CSV"]


class DummyThread(Thread):

    def __init__(self, event: Event):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.stop_event = event

    def run(self):
        while not self.stop_event.is_set():  
            sys.stdout.write("Searching %s device...\n"%(RPI_GADGET_IF_DESC))
            sys.stdout.flush()

            proc = subprocess.Popen(CMD, shell=False, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
            try:
                outs, errs = proc.communicate(timeout=15)

                #print(outs, errs)
            
                if b'No instances available' in errs:
                    sys.stdout.write("RNDIS device %s not ready!\n" %(RPI_GADGET_IF_DESC) )
                    sys.stdout.flush()
                else:
                    sys.stdout.write("RNDIS device %s ready!\n"%(RPI_GADGET_IF_DESC) )
                    sys.stdout.flush()    
                     
        
            except subprocess.TimeoutExpired:
                proc.kill()
                outs, errs = proc.communicate()

            time.sleep(5)
        sys.stdout.write("DummyThread done !\n")  
        sys.stdout.flush()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        e = Event() 
        t = DummyThread(e)
        t.start()
        while True:
            #print("Main thread running")
            time.sleep(0.5)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Stopping DummyThread...")
        e.set()
    finally:
        print("Main Exit")
```

Comment: Thanks for your elaborate response.. I got a good idea...However, I have to get a few things right based on ur sample code... (1) The Device description seems to be different (2) The WMIC NIC string seems to be fine when run in windows shell but seems to be invalid in the code.. may be an issue with formatting it in python.. (3) In case of Raspberry Pi, the MAC address keeps changing on every reboot. (4) I am not able to capture the data from proc.communicate() into outs variable, there seems to be some syntax issue. I use Python 3.7 and my Raspberry Pi OS is buster

Comment: @RaghavanK, I added working code in python3.7 (tested on Windows) edit at 03/08/2022. Also, this code assume your gadget already have an IP address (filter : `NetConnectionStatus=2`).